# How can I prevent node.js from printing the first SyntaxError it encounters when it parses the first module with an error?

Tags: javascript, node.js, v8

This is a weird one. If you require a module with a syntax error in it. You can catch the error, however node or v8 or some part of the system will print the syntax error to the console, even if you catch the error. You can replicate the issue by placing the following three files in the same directory and running "node example.js". How do I prevent this output? Redirecting isn't a viable solution, because I want to use stderr and stdout in my program. I want complete control of the error output. I've been searching through the V8 and node.js source, I can't seem to find where it is happening, so I can't tell how to stop it.

Thanks!

File one:

```
// example.js
try{ require('./error-one.js'); }
catch(e){ console.log("Caught:", e); }

try{ require('./error-two.js'); }
catch(e){ console.log("Caught:", e); }
```

File two:

```
// error-one.js
var a = { "b" c };
```

File three:

```
// error-two.js
var d = { "e" f };
```

EDIT: To clarify, the line I can't seem to remove is "var a = { "b" c};" with the arrows under it that appears before the caught errors. As I said in the comments, the odd part is that it doesn't appear twice. Only for the first file with a syntax error.

Comment: Code should not have syntax errors. It is unreasonable to deal with code that does.

Comment: How about a plugin system, exactly like the one I'm building? I need to bring in other peoples code, and I need to annotate error messages with extra information. I guess it's "unreasonable" to want to handle errors well. "It's unreasonable" is a great way to say: "I don't like thinking about things I don't know how to do, or understand the purpose of." Clearly the designers of the engine didn't think it was  "unreasonable". If they did I wouldn't be able to catch the SyntaxError exception in the first place.

Comment: Can you be more precise as to what the output should be?because i get the expected output according to your script.EDIT:i get "var a = { "b" c };" before the logs ,is it what your are talking about?

Comment: @mpm: yep. that line var a = { "b" c}; with the arrows under it. I can't seem to prevent that from reaching the console. It's weird that I don't get it for the second file, even though it has an error as well.

Comment: Halcyon is right, `require` is meant for completely different use case than what you are trying to force it into. How about just reading the file and calling eval on it?